# A series of graphviz diagrams in a single pdf file

Tags: python, graphviz

I create a graphviz diagram. Using below code.

```
  network1 = G.Digraph(
        graph_attr={...},
        node_attr={...},
        edge_attr={..} )
```

I add nodes

```
network1.node("node_edge_name",...)
```

...
and edges

```
network1.edge("A", "B")
```

...
and then call the below code. It creates me a pdf file and a dot file.

`network1.view(file_name)`.

This way my diagram becomes very complicated. What I want is, to create a series of network objects instead of one and to visualize them in a single pdf file page by page. In the end, I hope to have multiple dot files and a single pdf file.
Can someone describe if is there a way to do that and how?

Many thanks,
Ferda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used  PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter libraries to mege multiple pdf files into one. This was what I wanted.

```
pdf1File = open(file_name1, 'rb')
pdf2File = open(file_name2, 'rb')
pdf3File = open(file_name3, 'rb')
pdf4File = open(file_name4, 'rb')

# Read the files that you have opened
pdf1Reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf1File)
pdf2Reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf2File)
pdf3Reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf3File)
pdf4Reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf4File)

# Create a new PdfFileWriter object which represents a blank PDF document
pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

# Loop through all the pagenumbers for the first document
for pageNum in range(pdf1Reader.numPages):
    pageObj = pdf1Reader.getPage(pageNum)
    pdfWriter.addPage(pageObj)

# Loop through all the pagenumbers for the second document
for pageNum in range(pdf2Reader.numPages):
    pageObj = pdf2Reader.getPage(pageNum)
    pdfWriter.addPage(pageObj)

# Loop through all the pagenumbers for the third document
for pageNum in range(pdf3Reader.numPages):
    pageObj = pdf3Reader.getPage(pageNum)
    pdfWriter.addPage(pageObj)

# Loop through all the pagenumbers for the fourth document
for pageNum in range(pdf4Reader.numPages):
    pageObj = pdf4Reader.getPage(pageNum)
    pdfWriter.addPage(pageObj)

# Now that you have copied all the pages in both the documents, write them into the a new document
pdfOutputFile = open(file_name5+"_Merged_Files.pdf", 'wb')
pdfWriter.write(pdfOutputFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Graphviz does not seem to directly support this (maybe postscript output format does).  But there are several tools that will allow you to combine multiple pdfs into a single file.
This ghostscript command works:

```
 gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=combined.pdf -dBATCH  f1.pdf   f2.pdf  f3.pdf
```

See also: https://sites.astro.caltech.edu/observatories/coo/solicit/mergePDF.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem is that node positions may change from one graph to the next.  The **layers** feature will keep nodes from changing position (https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqOverlays)